# VBA Tree/Hierarchy

Tags: vba, tree, hierarchy

I am attempting to use Excel to fill in the blank cells in an organisational hierarchy I have. Before and After scenarios below.

I have attempted pseudocode on this.

[image: before]

[image: After]

```
For all rows
For all cells in row
If cell is populated, row++
If cell is not populated, copy the value immediately above to the current cell and check next cell in row.
```

1. Is this logic sound?
2. How would I go about implementing this in VBA?

Im guessing I can iterate through each cell in each row like this...

```
For Each row In rng.Rows
For Each cell in row.Cells
'Do Something
Next cell
Next row
```

but then I get stuck! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is sound.  Try something like this:

```
Sub FillTree()
Dim rng as Range
Dim r as Range
Dim c as Range
Dim cl as Range

Set rng = Range("A1:E50") '## Modify this to the full range you want to fill in.

For Each r In rng.Rows                     '# iterate over each column
    For Each cl in r.Cells                 '# check each cell in the column
        If Trim(cl) = vbNullString Then    '# if the cell is empty, fill from above
            cl = cl.Offset(-1,0)
        Else:                              '# skip to the next row if populated
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next 

End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm, this code isn't doing quite what I want. It is filling in cells C10 in the example. I don't quite understand why we iterate over columns before rows - surely it would be the other way around?     For Each c In rng.Columns

Comment: It shouldn't reallyt matter if you iterate rows/columns or columns/rows. Either way the code handles every cell in the matrix and either way we only check if the cell's empty and then fill from above value.  Can you describe in more detail what is not working correctly from this example?  It's possible I have a mistake in my answer and if like to fix it. Why don't you want c10 filled? I'm understanding this likea normal xml hierarchy but if that's not the case then I can revise my code.

Comment: I made a revision which I think better captures your intent. Let me know how that works.

Comment: David, this is perfect! I think it was the exit for statement which kicks it onto the next line when needed.

Comment: I changed it also to rows/columns, but you're right, I think that part is inconsequential and what made the difference was the `Exit For` statement.  Cheers!